# Is it possible to set a method's return type dynamically in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Take a look at this demo method first:

```
  Future<Product1Model> getProducts() async {
    String url = .......;
    var headers = {.......};

    var request = MultipartRequest('GET', Uri.parse(url));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = await response.stream.bytesToString();

      return Product1Method.Product1ModelFromJson(body);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Here you can see, the return type of this method is **Product1Model**. But, there might be many types of products and so that, I need to set the `return types`(Product1Model) and `response body decode method`(Product1Method.Product1ModelFromJson) dynamically to reuse the `getProducts` method.

So, is it possible to do this is Dart?
If possible, then how can I do this?

Comment: It's fundamentally impossible. The point of the declared return type is for *static* type-checking, but you want a return type that is determined only at runtime.

Comment: Do you know when calling your method what type you will return? Or you get to know this only when you get the response from the API?

Comment: Yes, I know the return types. There are different APIs to get different types of products. I want to reuse the getProducts function that's why I wanted to set the return type dynamically.

Comment: Good start would be to use generics: Future<T> getProducts<T>() async. You would call your method like this: getProducts<Product1Model>(). The only problem is - you are calling static method of another class to get the response, not sure how to do this. Ideally, your ProductxMethod should all have the same method name (e.g. ProducModelFromJson, and inherit from the same base class).

Comment: I posted my proposal below. Check if this works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
class Product1Model {
  String a;
  Product1Model(this.a);
}

class Product1Method {
  static Product1Model Product1ModelFromJson(String body) => Product1Model(body);
}

class Product2Model {
  String a;
  Product2Model(this.a);
}

class Product2Method {
  static Product2Model Product2ModelFromJson(String body) => Product2Model(body);
}


typedef ProductModelFromJson<T> = T Function(String);

Future<T> getProducts<T>(ProductModelFromJson<T> f) async {
      var body=T.runtimeType.toString();
      return f(body);
  }

main() async {
  var a= await getProducts<Product1Model>(Product1Method.Product1ModelFromJson);
  var b=await getProducts<Product2Model>(Product2Method.Product2ModelFromJson);
  
  print(a);
  print(b);
  
}
```

On second thought - your function should return 'body' variable:

```
Future<String> getProducts() async {
    String url = .......;
    var headers = {.......};

    var request = MultipartRequest('GET', Uri.parse(url));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = await response.stream.bytesToString();

      return body;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

And then - since you know when calling which type you are expecting:

```
Product1Method.Product1ModelFromJson(getProducts());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. You helped me to reduce many lines of code. Your first one is my expected answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean sometimes it will return `Product1Model` sometimes it will return `Product2Model`, if that is the case then NO, i would suggest making it `Future<dynamic>` or `Future<Object>`. you can take a look at `either` and `tuple` also

Comment: yes, I need sometimes product1model and sometimes product2model and so on. But if it would possible then it would be helped me a lot to reduce lots of my code to decode dynamic types of products.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning Future

```
  Future<dynamic> getProducts() async {
    String url = .......;
    var headers = {.......};

    var request = MultipartRequest('GET', Uri.parse(url));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = await response.stream.bytesToString();

      return Product1Method.Product1ModelFromJson(body);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Or Future

```
  Future<Object> getProducts() async {
    String url = .......;
    var headers = {.......};

    var request = MultipartRequest('GET', Uri.parse(url));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = await response.stream.bytesToString();

   c   return Product1Method.Product1ModelFromJson(body);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

And then you can set up a receiver at the other end to check what its type is by doing something like

```
dynamic x = await getProducts();
if (x is Product1Model){
  //Something
}
else if (x is Product2Model){
   //Something
}
```

Or switch statement

```
dynamic x = await getProducts();
switch(x.runtimeType){
  case (Product1Model()):
  //Something
  case (Product2Model()):
   //Something
}
```

Or if you have a one liner code in Something,

```
x is Product1Model? Something: x is Product2Model?Something: And so on
```

Comment: I did this in the same way you explain but, I just wanted to know that, if it would possible then lots of code can be reduced.

Comment: What part do u want to reduce? The x is Product1Model part? You need to have some sort of way to get it, you can use switch statements, which is a little shorter or the ? operator which is way shorter but only works for 1 liners

Comment: These are the only ways I could think of reducing the code

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation. Actually, there are not only these two products model. I have lots of product models. That's why I wanted to set the return type dynamically to reuse the getProducts method if it would be possible. I don't want this solution as I already implement this in my code. But, I am really thankful to you to cooperate with me.